# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined on the float box

Tags: javascript

I am getting the following error on all browsers while opening the float box and then it cannot be closed. You need to refresh the page. There was no problem before. It was working fine. Now, I've been getting this error ever since I adapted the new design to the site. How can fix this problem? Thank you.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined
```

```js
// disabling/enabling
jQuery.fn.extend({
    disable: function() {
        this.each(function()
        {
            this.disabled = true;

            if ( this.tagName != 'INPUT' && this.tagName != 'TEXTAREA' && this.tagName != 'SELECT' )
            {
                this.jQuery_disabled_clone =
                    jQuery(this)
                    .addClass('disabled')
                    .clone()
                    .removeAttr('id')
                    .get(0);

                jQuery(this)
                    .hide()
                    .bind('unload', function(){
                        jQuery(this).enable();
                    })
                    .after(this.jQuery_disabled_clone);
            }
        });

        return this;
    },

    enable: function()
    {
        this.each(function()
        {
            this.disabled = false;

            if ( this.jQuery_disabled_clone )
            {
                jQuery(this.jQuery_disabled_clone).remove();
                this.jQuery_disabled_clone = null;

                jQuery(this)
                    .unbind('unload', function(){
                        jQuery(this).enable();
                    })
                    .removeClass('disabled')
                    .show();
            }
        });

        return this;
    }
});


function SK_Exception(message, code)
{
    this.toString = function() {
        return message;
    }

    this.getCode = function() {
        return code;
    }
}

function SK_drawError(err_msg, delay) {
    SK_drawMessage(err_msg, 'error', delay);
}

function SK_drawMessage(msg_text, type, delay)
{
    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' && (msg_text == "Virtual gift has been sent" || msg_text == "Hediyeniz başarıyla gönderildi.." || msg_text == "Virtual gift has not been sent" || msg_text == "Hediyeniz gönderilemedi.."))
    alert(msg_text);

    type = type || 'message';
    delay = delay || (1000*10);
    if (SK_drawMessage.in_process) {
        if (msg_text) {
            SK_drawMessage.queue.unshift([msg_text, type, delay]);
        }
        return;
    }

    if (!msg_text) {
        var item = SK_drawMessage.queue.shift();
        if (!item) {
            return;
        }
        msg_text = item[0];
        type = item[1];
        delay = item[2];
    }

    SK_drawMessage.in_process = true;

    // getting draw position
    var $last = jQuery('.macos_msg_node:last');
    var top_pos = (!$last.length) ? 0 : $last.position().top + $last.outerHeight() + 2;
    
    var $msg_block =
        // creating message block
        jQuery('<div class="macos_msg_node macos_'+type+'" style="display: none"></div>')
            .appendTo('body')
            .html(msg_text)
            
            .prepend('<a class="close_btn" href="#"></a>')
            .css('top', top_pos)
            .fadeTo(50, 0.1, function() {
                jQuery(this).css('display', '');
                SK_drawMessage.in_process = false;
                SK_drawMessage();
                jQuery(this).fadeTo(300, 1, function() {

                    if (delay > 0) {
                        window.setTimeout(function() {
                            try {
                                $msg_block.fadeOut(2500, function() {
                                    jQuery(this).remove();
                                });
                            } catch (e) {alert(e);}
                        }, delay);
                    }
                });
            });
    $msg_block.children('.close_btn')
        .click(function() {
            jQuery(this).parent().fadeOut(100, function() {
                jQuery(this).remove();
            });
            return false;
        }
    );

}
SK_drawMessage.in_process = false;
SK_drawMessage.queue = [];




/**
 * Float box constructor.
 *
 * @param string|jQuery $title
 * @param string|jQuery $contents
 * @param jQuery $controls
 * @param object position {top, left} = center
 * @param integer width = auto
 * @param integer height = auto
 */
function SK_FloatBox(options)
{
    var fb_class;

    if (typeof document.body.style.maxHeight === 'undefined') { //if IE 6
        jQuery('body').css({height: '100%', width: '100%'});
        jQuery('html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
        if (document.getElementById('floatbox_HideSelect') === null) { //iframe to hide select elements in ie6
            jQuery('body').append('<iframe id="floatbox_HideSelect"></iframe><div id="floatbox_overlay"></div>');
            fb_class = SK_FloatBox.detectMacXFF() ? 'floatbox_overlayMacFFBGHack' : 'floatbox_overlayBG';
            jQuery('#floatbox_overlay').addClass(fb_class);
        }
    }
    else { //all others
        if (document.getElementById('floatbox_overlay') === null) {
            jQuery('body').append('<div id="floatbox_overlay"></div>');
            fb_class = SK_FloatBox.detectMacXFF() ? 'floatbox_overlayMacFFBGHack' : 'floatbox_overlayBG';
            jQuery('#floatbox_overlay').addClass(fb_class);
        }
    }

    jQuery('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');

    this.$container = jQuery('.floatbox_container', '#sk-floatbox-block-prototype').clone().appendTo('body');

    this.$header = this.$container.find('.block_cap_title');

    if (typeof options.$title == 'string') {
        options.$title = jQuery('<span>'+options.$title+'</span>');
    }
    else {
        this.$title_parent = options.$title.parent();
    }

    this.$header.append(options.$title);

    this.$body = this.$container.find('.block_body_c');

    if (typeof options.$contents == 'string') {
        options.$contents = jQuery('<span>'+options.$contents+'</span>');
    }
    else {
        this.$contents_parent = options.$contents.parent();
    }

    this.$body.append(options.$contents);

    this.$bottom = this.$container.find('.block_bottom_c');

    if (options.$controls) {
        if (typeof options.$controls == 'string') {
            options.$controls = jQuery('<span>'+options.$controls+'</span>');
        }
        else {
            this.$controls_parent = options.$controls.parent();
        }

        this.$bottom.append(options.$controls);
    }

    if (options.width)
        this.$container.css("width", options.width);
    if (options.height)
        this.$container.css("height", options.height);

    var fl_box = this;
    jQuery('.close_btn', this.$container.find('.floatbox_header'))
        .one('click', function() {
            fl_box.close();
            return false;
        });

    this.esc_listener =
    function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 27) {
            fl_box.close();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    jQuery(document).bind('keydown', this.esc_listener);

    this.$container
        .fadeTo(1, 0.1, function()
        {
            var $this = jQuery(this);

            $this.css('display', 'block');

            if (options.position) {
                $this.css(options.position);
            }
            else {
                var position = {
                    top:((jQuery(window).height()/2) - ($this.height()/2))/*.ceil()*/,
                    left:((jQuery(window).width()/2) - ($this.width()/2))/*.ceil()*/
                };

                $this.css(position);
            }

            // trigger on show event
            fl_box.trigger('show');

            $this.fadeTo(100, 1);
        });

    this.events = {close: [], show: []};
}

SK_FloatBox.detectMacXFF = function()
{
    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    return (userAgent.indexOf('mac') != -1 && userAgent.indexOf('firefox') != -1);
}

SK_FloatBox.prototype = {
    close: function()
    {
        if (this.trigger('close') === false) {
            return false;
        }

        jQuery(document).unbind('keydown', this.esc_listener);

        if (this.$title_parent && this.$title_parent.length) {
            this.$title_parent.append(
                this.$header.children()
            );
        }
        if (this.$contents_parent && this.$contents_parent.length) {
            this.$contents_parent.append(this.$body.children());
        }
        if (this.$controls_parent && this.$controls_parent.length) {
            this.$controls_parent.append(this.$bottom.children());
        }

        this.$container.remove();

        if (jQuery('.floatbox_container:not("#sk-floatbox-block-prototype .floatbox_container")').length === 0) {
            jQuery('body').css('overflow', '');
            jQuery('#floatbox_overlay, #floatbox_HideSelect').remove();
        }

        return true;
    },

    bind: function(type, func)
    {
        if (this.events[type] == undefined) {
            throw 'form error: unknown event type "'+type+'"';
        }

        this.events[type].push(func);

    },

    trigger: function(type, params)
    {
        if (this.events[type] == undefined) {
            throw 'form error: unknown event type "'+type+'"';
        }

        params = params || [];

        for (var i = 0, func; func = this.events[type][i]; i++) {
            if (func.apply(this, params) === false) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}


function SK_alert($title, $contents, callback)
{
    if (!callback &&
        typeof $contents == 'function' &&
        $contents.constructor != Array) {
        callback = $contents;
    }

    if (!$contents || $contents == callback) {
        $contents = $title;
        $title = SK_Language.text('%interface.alert_title');
    }

    var $ok_btn =
        jQuery('<input type="button" />')
        .val(SK_Language.text('%interface.ok'));

    var fl_box = new SK_FloatBox({
        $title: $title,
        $contents: $contents,
        $controls: $ok_btn
    });

    $ok_btn.one('click', function() {
        fl_box.close();
        if (callback) {
            callback.apply(fl_box);
        }
    });

    return fl_box;
}


function SK_confirm($title, $contents, callback)
{
    if (!callback &&
        typeof $contents == 'function' &&
        $contents.constructor != Array) {
        callback = $contents;
    }

    if (!$contents || $contents == callback) {
        $contents = $title;
        $title = SK_Language.text('%interface.confirmation_title');
    }

    var $ok_btn =
        jQuery('<input type="button" />')
        .val(SK_Language.text('%interface.ok'));

    var $cancel_btn =
        jQuery('<input type="button" />')
        .val(SK_Language.text('%interface.cancel'));

    var fl_box = new SK_FloatBox({
        $title: $title,
        $contents: $contents,
        $controls: jQuery($ok_btn)
                    .add('<span>&nbsp;</span>')
                    .add($cancel_btn)
    });

    $ok_btn.one('click', function() {
        fl_box.close();
        if (callback) {
            callback.apply(fl_box);
        }
    });

    $cancel_btn.one('click', function() {
        fl_box.close();
    });

    return fl_box;
}



function SK_BlockHandler(block_node)
{
    this.$block = jQuery(block_node);

    this.$block_cap =
        jQuery('.block_cap:eq(0)', this.$block);

    this.$title =
        jQuery('.block_cap_title:eq(0)', this.$block_cap);

    this.$body =
        jQuery('.block_body:eq(0)', this.$block);

    this.$expand_btn =
        jQuery('.block_expand:eq(0), .block_collapse:eq(0)', this.$block_cap);

    this.events = {
        click: [],
        expand: [],
        collapse: []
    }

    var handler = this;

    this.$block_cap
        .click(function() {
            if (handler.$expand_btn.hasClass('block_expand')) {
                handler.expand();
            }
            else if (handler.$expand_btn.hasClass('block_collapse')) {
                handler.collapse();
            }
            return false;
        });
}

SK_BlockHandler.prototype = {

    expand: function(trigger_events)
    {
        if (trigger_events === undefined) {
            trigger_events = true;
        }

        if (!trigger_events || (
            this.trigger('expand') !== false
            && this.trigger('click') !== false)
        ) {
            this.$expand_btn.attr('class', 'block_collapse');
            this.$body.slideDown('fast');
        }

        return this;
    },

    collapse: function(trigger_events)
    {
        if (trigger_events === undefined) {
            trigger_events = true;
        }

        if (!trigger_events || (
            this.trigger('collapse') !== false
            && this.trigger('click') !== false)
        ) {
            this.$expand_btn.attr('class', 'block_expand');
            this.$body.slideUp('fast');
        }

        return this;
    },

    show: function(speed, callback) {
        this.$block.show(speed, callback);
    },

    hide: function(speed, callback) {
        this.$block.hide(speed, callback);
    },

    bind: function(type, arg1, arg2)
    {
        if (this.events[type] == undefined) {
            throw 'block error: unknown event type "'+type+'"';
        }

        if (!arg2) {
            this.events[type].push([arg1]);
        }
        else {
            this.events[type].push([arg1, arg2]);
        }
    },

    trigger: function(type)
    {
        if (this.events[type] == undefined) {
            throw 'block error: unknown event type "'+type+'"';
        }

        for (var i = 0, item; item = this.events[type][i]; i++)
        {
            if (item.length == 1) {
                if (item[0].apply(this) === false) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else if (item[1].call(this, item[0]) === false) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    },

    clone: function(clone_e)
    {
        var $clone = this.$block.clone();
        var node = $clone.get(0);

        node.sk_block_handler = new SK_BlockHandler(node);

        if (clone_e) {
            node.sk_block_handler.events = this.events;
        }

        return node.sk_block_handler;
    },

    append: function(content) {
        return this.$body.append(content);
        return this;
    },

    appendTo: function(content) {
        this.$block.appendTo(content);
        return this;
    },

    empty: function() {
        this.$body.empty();
        return this;
    },

    children: function(expr) {
        return this.$body.children(expr).not('.block_body_corner');
    },

    find: function(expr) {
        return this.$body.find(expr).not('.block_body_corner');
    },

    removeAttr: function(name) {
        this.$block.removeAttr(name);
        return this;
    },

    addClass: function(cls) {
        this.$block.addClass(cls);
        return this;
    },

    removeClass: function(cls) {
        this.$block.removeClass(cls);
        return this;
    }
}

jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.block_expand, .block_collapse')
        .each(function() {
            var block_node = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
            if (jQuery(block_node).hasClass('block')) {
                block_node.sk_block_handler = new SK_BlockHandler(block_node);
            }
        });
});



SK_Language = {

    data: {},

    text: function(lang_addr, var_list)
    {
        if ( SK_Language.data[lang_addr] === undefined ) {
            throw new SK_Exception('language section ['+lang_addr+'] not found');
        }

        var text = SK_Language.data[lang_addr];

        if (var_list) {
            for ( key in var_list ) {
                text = text.replace('{$'+key+'}', var_list[key]);
            }
        }

        return text;
    }
}

function nl2br(str) {
    return (str + '').replace(/([^>]?)\n/g, '$1<br />\n');
}

function SK_SignIn() {
    return window.sk_component_sign_in.showBox();
}

function SK_openIM(opponent_id, is_esd)
{
    if (is_esd)
        is_esd_session = '&is_esd_session='+is_esd;
    else
        is_esd_session = '';
    return window.open(
        URL_MEMBER+'im.php?opponent_id='+opponent_id+is_esd_session,
        'im_with_'+opponent_id,
        'width='+SK_openIM.width+','+
        'height='+SK_openIM.height+','+
        'resizable=yes, location=no, scrollbars=no, status=no'
    );
}
SK_openIM.width = 445;
SK_openIM.height = 460;

function SK_profileNote( event_id, opponent_id)
{
    return window.open(
        URL_MEMBER+'profile_note.php?event_id='+event_id+'&opponent_id='+opponent_id,
        'note_'+opponent_id,
        'width='+SK_profileNote.width+','+
        'height='+SK_profileNote.height+','+
        'resizable=yes, location=no, scrollbars=no, status=no'
    );
}
SK_profileNote.width = 325;
SK_profileNote.height = 425;

SK_EventManager = {

    events: {},

    bind: function(event, callback)
    {
        if ( typeof this.events[event] == 'undefined' || this.events[event] === null)
        {
            this.events[event] = [];
        }

        this.events[event].push(callback);
    },

    trigger: function(event, eventObject)
    {
        if (typeof this.events[event] != 'undefined' && this.events[event] !== null)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.events[event].length; i++)
            {
                if (typeof this.events[event][i] == 'function')
                {
                    if (this.events[event][i](eventObject) === false)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

SK_SetFieldInvitation = function(id, label)
{
    var $node = $('#' + id);
    $node.addClass('input_invitation').val(label);

    $node.focus(function() {
        var v = $node.val();
        $node.removeClass('input_invitation');

        if ( v == label )
        {
            $node.val('');
        }
    }).blur(function() {
        var v = $node.val();
        if ( !v )
        {
            $node.addClass('input_invitation').val(label);
        }
    });

    $($node.get(0).form).submit(function(){
        if ( $node.val() != label )
        {
            $node.removeClass('input_invitation');
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="floatbox_container" style="overflow: visible; width: 320px; opacity: 0.1; display: block; top: 274px; left: 736px;">
            <div class="block_cap floatbox_header"><div class="block_cap_r"><div class="block_cap_c clearfix"><h3 class="block_cap_title"><b>Şifremi unuttum!</b></h3><a class="close_btn" href="#"></a></div></div></div>      <div class="floatbox_body">
        <div class="fblock_body block_body">
         <div class="fblock_body_r block_body_r">
          <div class="fblock_body_c block_body_c">
          <div class="block_info">Şifremi yenile</div><form id="form_3" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
                <label>E-posta</label>: <input id="form_3-email" name="email" type="text" maxlength="255">
<div id="form_3-email-container"></div>
            <div class="controls center float_left">
                <input id="form_3-send-button" type="submit" value="Gönder">            </div>
            <div class="clr"></div>
        </form></div>
         </div>
        </div>
             </div>
         <div class="floatbox_bottom">  
        <div class="block_bottom">
         <div class="block_bottom_r">
           <div class="block_bottom_c">
           </div>
                  </div>
          </div>
               </div>
        <div class="fblock_bottom">
            <div class="fblock_bottom_r">
            <div class="fblock_bottom_c"></div>
            </div>
        </div>


        </div>
```

Comment: to get rid of this error i suggest using optional chaining es20 feature. your app won't crash at least

Comment: Hi, i am newbie. Could you explain more detailed and simpler please?

Comment: I haven't read your code but at least with optional chaining you can get rid of this error. but you have to fix the logic by yourself. More info : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: Thank you very much Ehsan but i am sorry  i have no so much information and skill to do it for now. Just learning now. I thought that maybe i can fix and do something via some instructions given by the experienced ones